# How to get path to the parent folder of a certain directory?

Tags: delphi

When I would have this directory path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\
```

The function I'm looking for should return:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

I've tried this code but it works only for files, not for directories:

```
function GetParentDirectory(const Path: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExpandFileName(Path);
end;
```

Does anyone know what should I use to return path to the parent folder of a certain directory ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a couple of ways:

From a folder name:

```
ExtractFilePath(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter('C:\Parent\Child\'));
```

From a file name:

```
ExtractFilePath(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath('C:\Parent\Child\app.exe')));
```

Answer (score 17):

In newer versions of delphi you could use `TDirectory` from `IOUtils`

```
TDirectory.GetParent(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(YourPath))
```

Comment: Why doesn't GetParent deal with delimiters rather than requiring the user to type that extremely long function name? From the documentation: "Returns the parent directory of another directory." If it's expecting to passed in a directory then the trailing delimiter should be irrelevant.

Comment: @alcalde There is a difference between *Path* and *Directory* (the trailing PathDelimiter) and it matters

Comment: @SirRufo, what is the difference exactly?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ExtractFileDir('C:\Path\Path2') gives 'C:\Path'
```

Note that

```
ExtractFileDir('C:\Path\Path2\') gives 'C:\Path\Path2'
```

Thanks to TLama:

```
ExtractFileDir(ExcludeTrailingBackslash('C:\Path\Path2')) gives 'C:\Path'
ExtractFileDir(ExcludeTrailingBackslash('C:\Path\Path2\')) gives 'C:\Path'
```

Comment: The user asks for a function that will take an input like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\\` and return `C:\Program Files (x86)\\`. Your function returns `C:\Program Files (x86)` and so therefore does not meet the requirement. Instead of `ExtractFileDir` you need to call `ExtractFilePath`.